# Formatting a Date stored in the DB

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm updating some very old PHP (3 I think) to PHP 5.6 and am having problems getting the time formatted for old posts. The date is stored in the MySQL database and I can retrieve that fine - but the old code delivers a `null` output.  Everything I read about formatting seems to assume I want the current date.  I want to `2012-11-09 14:17:18` to just read `2012-11-09 14:17`

Here is the original code from the ancient version of the phorum:

```
$datestamp = date_format($head_row["datestamp"]);
echo $datestamp
```

but that produces an empty nothingness, so I changed it to:

```
$datestamp = ($head_row["datestamp"]);
```

and that gives me the whole saved datestamp.  How do I cut off the seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is strtotime.

```
$datestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($head_row["datestamp"]));
```

Answer (score 1):

this will give you exactly what you need

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $head_row["datestamp"]);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

and thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the php format sting to time function:

```
$datestamp = date('n/j/Y', strtotime($head_row["datestamp"])); // ex. 4/9/2015
$datestamp = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($head_row["datestamp"])); // ex. 04/09/2015
```

Here is the link to the different kinds of formats that php provides
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php